# UI Control library for the .NET Micro Framework

Tags: c#, controls, .net-micro-framework

Does anybody know of a UI Control library for the .NET Micro Framework?

Doing everything from scratch is a real pain sometimes :p

Answer (score 4):

Well, for commercial solutions, you could try:

[Rich Media Extensions for the .NET Micro Framework from Innobedded](http://innobedded.com/product.html)

[Right View by BlueDev Ltd.](http://www.bluedev.eu/t2c/ProductsSolutions/UserInterface/RightView/tabid/171/language/en-US/Default.aspx)

Other than those, there's some interesting links to other resources in this area, such as:

[Widgets on Micro Framework](http://www.microframework.nl/2009/09/18/widgets-on-micro-framework/) on Elze Kool's blog

[Micro XAML Tool](http://informatix.miloush.net/microframework/Utilities/MicroXaml.aspx) by Jan Kučera

A blog post from Kevin Pfister regarding "[Designing my .Net Micro Framework Widget Toolkit](http://blogplusequals.blogspot.com/2009/03/designing-my-net-micro-framework-widget.html)"

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Glide ?

http://netmfglide.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

[innobedded.com](http://innobedded.com/) have a Rich Media Extensions product.

Answer (score 0):

Hongfeng Liu (of Microsoft China) created [TinyGUI](http://www.fezzer.com/project/208/tinygui-a-small-library-for-gui-applications/) ([original post](http://blog.csdn.net/yefanqiu/archive/2010/05/20/5612682.aspx) in Chinese).

From [the post](http://www.fezzer.com/project/208/tinygui-a-small-library-for-gui-applications/) by [terrorgen](http://www.fezzer.com/user/1442/) on FEZZer.com:

> The official UI library for
>   Microsoft's .Net MF is WPF. For
>   320x240 LCDs, an extra 150K of RAM is
>   needed to barely run the library.
>   However, only the EMX module in GHI's
>   products (>12MB user RAM) can offer
>   the privilege. Also, since most .NET
>   MF processors' main clock speed is
>   around 72MHz, the official UI library
>   is slower.
>
> TinyGUI uses a technology similar to
>   DirectDraw, which deals with display
>   memory directly without requiring
>   processor RAM. Therefore it's 3x - 5x
>   faster as the author has claimed.

Comment: This is another example of how I love Eastern ways of thinking... Just like me in so many ways :P

This can actually make for a very malicious virii if used inappropriately :P